# What does なんだって mean in this case? 「そういう子なんだってだけで...」

Tags: translation

I saw this sentence in manga and I had trouble with it:

> そういう子なんだってだけで俺が怒ってもどうしようもない

I would like to know how we can translate なんだって in this case.

Comment: Please provide us with a context of your efforts

Comment: There is a conversation between two characters. One of them says 「おまえ、裏切られたんだぞ？　おれはああいうのぜったい無理。」Then the other character answers him the sentence which I wrote above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> そういう子**なんだって**だけで俺{おれ}が怒{おこ}ってもどうしようもない

「なんだって」 in this sentence is the informal form of 「なのだという」.

Thus, in the first half of the sentence, someone is being described as 「そういう子なんだ/なのだ」 ("***S/he is just that type of kid/person***.")

Having said that, this sentence can still mean ***two*** different things without further context. Those are:

> 1. "S/he is just that type of kid **and** there is no point in me getting angry (about it)."

> 2. "There is no point in me getting angry **only because** s/he is that kind of kid."

One of the two should fit the context. There could not be another meaning.

***Other common usages of 「なんだって」:***

・Synonymous with 「なんでも」 ("***anything***"). Informal form of 「なんであっても」

「暑{あつ}い！なにか飲{の}み物{もの}ない？飲み物なら**なんだって**いい。」

・Synonymous with 「なぜ」 ("***why***"). Informal form of 「なんだといって」.

「**なんだって**一人で夜{よる}に新宿{しんじゅく}なんか行ったの！」